# displays the most read Document IN MOSS

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have to write WEBPART,
 That displays the most read Document IN MOSS
 From where I can read this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look @ [Order documents by most popular in sharepoint content query webpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017302/order-documents-by-most-popular-in-sharepoint-content-query-webpart)